# Invalid XLS format in windows 8 cmd prompt

Tags: cmd, xls

I am trying to run this command to get the cpu format list and redirect it to a file. But on execution of that command i get a error says that invalid XLS format (or) file type

wmic:root\cli>CPU Get/Format:List > cpu.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
wmic CPU Get /Format:List > cpu.txt
```

Notes:

- You cannot redirect output when you are in a `wmic` prompt.